# Make Footer stay on bottom

Tags: html, css, image, footer

I think my coding is correct, but I still can't put the footer to the bottom of the page, and I really need to do it.

The footer on the result appears directly under the header which is annoying as I want it to go into my main `div` which is located in my `body`.

Thanks. :)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Gallery</title>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="mobile.css"/>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="header">
           <div id="companyname">Shutter Up Photography</div>
           <div id="nav">
               <ul>
                   <li><a href="contactus.html">Contact Us</a></li>
                   <li><a href="experience.html">Experience</a></li>
                   <li><a href="offers.html">Offers</a></li>
                   <li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
                   <li><a href="location.html">Location</a></li>
                   <li><a href="aboutus.html">About Us</a></li>
                   <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
               </ul>
           </div>
       </div>

       <div id="main">
           <div id="content">
               <div class="img">
                   <img src="img_model.jpg"/>
                   <div class="desc">Model Shot</div>
               </div>

               <div class="img">
                   <img src="img_classy.jpg"/>
                   <div class="desc">A classy family shot</div>
               </div>

               <div class="img">
                   <img src="img_father.jpg"/>
                   <div class="desc">A father and his boys</div>
               </div>

               <div class="img">
                   <img src="img_wedding.jpg"/>
                   <div class="desc">Timeless Wedding Shot</div>
               </div>

               <div class="img">
                   <img src="img_mother.jpg"/>
                   <div class="desc">A mother and her children</div>
               </div>

               <div class="img">
                   <img src="img_kid.jpg"/>
                   <div class="desc">Imaginative Kid</div>
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>

       <div id="footer">
           <div id="companyname">Shutter Up Photography</div>
      </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

[This is the result from my coding, I've tried to put the css gallery into the main div, but won't work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VDJ4W.png)

[This is my css code for it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zyhtw.png)

Comment: Please add your CSS as code (not an image) - you can edit your question and add another `code` block

Comment: Try laying out the regions of your page using flexbox: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Please add your CSS code into the post itself, not just a link.

Comment: Post your css here instead of in an image. I've created a jsfiddle for you with your HTML. Throw in your CSS and we'll go from there. https://jsfiddle.net/zsL3ww9j/

Comment: I can't just add an image cause this site says I need 10 credits or something like that

Answer (score 1):

Its because your images are being floated which takes them out of the flow of the page.

Try this

```
div div div.img {
  margin: 5px;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 400px;
}
```

By removing the float and replacing with inline block you keep the elements within the flow of the page.

**EDIT -**

HTML -

```
<div class="img">
    <img/>

</div><div class="img">
    <img/>

</div><div class="img">
    <img/>

</div>
```

If you choose to use inline-block, layer your html like this, as inline-block elements take into consideration the white space between elements.

**/ EDIT **

Or if you wish to keep the float, create a clearfix class and attach it to the parent

```
.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

EDIT -

```
<div id="content" class="clearfix">
    <!-- your floated divs here -->
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Mark will try.

Comment: Hey Mark, even if I did the inline block element to put it with the flow of the page, how would I then get it to look like 3x2 gallery like before??

Comment: Please check my edit :) @M.Park

Comment: what if I kept the float, but the elements just go with the page flow and stack up in a column, how do I then put them into displaying a 3x2 look.

Comment: @M.Park if Mark's answer solved the problem, mark it as such.  Then, ask separate questions for the remaining issues

Answer (score 1):

Add a wrapper with the following CSS attributes as the code below.  This should do the trick:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
#wrap {
  min-height: 100%;
}
#main {
  overflow: auto;
  padding-bottom: 150px;
  /* must be same height as the footer */
}
#footer {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -150px;
  /* negative value of footer height */
  height: 150px;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  clear: both;
  background-color: #006BFE;
  border: 2px solid red;
  /* remove border, showns for illustration purposes only */
}
div.img {
  margin: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 400px;
  border: 1px solid blue;  
    padding: 10px;
}
div.img img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  border: 2px solid #006bFE;  

}
div.desc {
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}
.somelist {
  list-style-type: square;
  list-style-position: inside;
  float: none;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  background-color: #93dbfe;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
  <div id="header">
    <div id="companyname">Shutter Up Photography</div>
    <div id="nav">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="contactus.html">Contact Us</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="experience.html">Experience</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="offers.html">Offers</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="location.html">Location</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="aboutus.html">About Us</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="home.html">Home</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="main">
    <div id="content">
      <div class="img">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/300/people" />
        <div class="desc">Model Shot</div>
      </div>

      <div class="img">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/300/people" />
        <div class="desc">A classy family shot</div>
      </div>

      <div class="img">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/300/people" />
        <div class="desc">A father and his boys</div>
      </div>

      <div class="img">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/300/people" />
        <div class="desc">Timeless Wedding Shot</div>
      </div>

      <div class="img">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/300/people" />
        <div class="desc">A mother and her children</div>
      </div>

      <div class="img">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/300/people" />
        <div class="desc">Imaginative Kid</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="footer">
  <div id="companyname">Shutter Up Photography</div>
</div>
```